# Nautilus Confirm Delete Script?

Tags: nautilus

It's no secret that the delete confirmation feature in Nautilus (version 2.24.1 anyway) does not work when deleting a file despite having the option check to confirm in the prefs window so I was wondering if there was a script available that would show a confirm delete dialog when deleting files within nautilus.

Thx,
Kami

Comment: I know this question isn't actually 'solved' as such, but since it's been established that no such script exists could you please accept my answer so that people can see easily that the question needs no further attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean moving to trash, or *permanently* deleting? The option `Ask before emptying the Wastebasket or deleting files` only affects permanent deletes.

As far as I know, there is currently no script that will do what you want.

[GNOME Bugzilla – Bug 316807](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316807)

Comment: I mean simply selecting a file and then clicking on the delete key but as you said there is no script for that or no undo feature either it seems. It appears to be a rather large oversight on the nautilus developers part but you get what you pay for I suppose.

Kami